# browser URL using Javascript without refreshing the page and change div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

Im wondering if it's possible to change the URL at the same time using the code below?

Found some code at this [link](http://hasin.me/2013/10/16/manipulating-url-using-javascript-without-freshing-the-page/) that change the URL but i can't get them to work together.

Is it even possible or is there an better (working) solution?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(function(){
    $('#profileMenu li a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var page_url=$(this).prop('href');
        $('#profileContent').load(page_url);
    });
});
</script>
  </head>
  <body>


<div id="profileMenu">
    <ul id="profileMenu">
        <li><a href="page1.asp">page 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="page2.asp">page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>​
<div id="profileContent"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's probably not working because you have **two** instances of the same `id`.  jQuery will ignore the second instance which would break your selector.

Comment: do you want to load another page without page refresh..???
or change content on same page just want to change a url??

Comment: That example link uses `history.pushstate()` and your example doesn't.

Comment: Evaluating the code answers some questions.  `<a>` tags are being used with `href` to change the URL.  A jQuery `.on` event handler listens for the `<a>` tag to be clicked.  The URL is being changed, probably for `Deep Linking` capabilities.  Content in the `<div>` element `profileContent` is meant to be changed by the short hand jQuery Ajax method `.load`.  Regardless of the problem with two identical id's, the function triggers when the `<a>` tags are clicked.  So I don't think that is the problem.  The `.load` method is probably not finding the URL.  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WL5yb/)

Comment: You need to know whether the ajax `.load` method is failing or not.  Use some type of developer tool in your browser to see if there are any error messages in the console.  For example, in `Chrome`, `Tools` `Developer Tools`, or `Firebug`.

Comment: @SandyGood, The question is written so poorly that nobody really knows what the OP is looking for.  I've rolled back all revisions to the OP's last version.

Comment: @Sparky So, you've intentionally changed everything back to something inferior?  Is that just out of spite?  Rolling everything back to something that's hard to understand doesn't help people who are using this site to find answers.  I'm trying to improve content for anyone who happens to be searching for answers.  So, you don't like bad content on this site, but you are going to intentionally roll it back to really bad content?  That is as stupid as it gets.  If you are concerned that a well worded question would get the OP lots of points that they don't deserve, then change the point system.

Comment: @SandyGood, I didn't earn my reputation out of spite.  The question is terrible and if the OP can't clarify it, it needs to be closed.  It's not our job to _guess_ what the OP wants and rewrite the entire question to fit that theory.  Please spend a little more time learning about how things are done before making all kinds of wild assumptions and accusations, and visit http://meta.stackoverflow.com to discuss matters like this in detail.

Comment: @Sparky I don't care how many points you have.  How many points you have doesn't automatically mean your are right.  The OP can make the decision if anyone's edit is helpful or correct.  This site allow people to edit the OP's content.  If that's wrong, then change the way the site works.  Part of my edit that you deleted explained the code.  There is no guess work there.  So why did you delete that?  So, you are the authority here on the site who tells people what their job is and isn't?  Please let me know.

Comment: @SandyGood, again ->> visit http://meta.stackoverflow.com to discuss matters like this in detail.

Comment: @SandyGood, editing privileges are not unlimited:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, this used to be impossible in plain JavaScript.
However, with HTML5 you can use combination of `pushState` method and `onpopstate` event.

Basically, you do `pushState` to change URL and push some user data into history without refreshing the page, and change data in your `div`. If you navigate through history via either BACK/FORWARD buttons or JS, an `onpopstate` event will fire providing your pushed user data and changing back the URL so that you can handle it to display cached page.

This technique is described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

More about `onpopstate` event - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onpopstate

Comment: @Sparky yes, and AFAIU from **question title**, he wants to change URL in address bar without reloading the page. However, looking at the **provided source code** it seems like he simply wants AJAX. So his question is not very well-formed.